# Cannot Concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Tags: string, python-2.7, tuples, python-requests

I am trying to make a shoe size to shoe code converter and use the conversion as a parameter for form data in python 2.7 requests

```
Size = raw_input('Size Number: ')
if Size=='4':
    sizenumber = '530',
elif Size=='4.5':
    sizenumber = '540',
elif Size=='5':
    sizenumber = '550',
elif Size=='5.5':
    sizenumber = '560',
elif Size=='6':
    sizenumber = '570',
elif Size=='6.5':
    sizenumber = '580',
elif Size=='7':
    sizenumber = '590',
elif Size=='7.5':
    sizenumber = '600',
elif Size=='8':
    sizenumber = '610',
elif Size=='8.5':
    sizenumber = '620',
elif Size=='9':
    sizenumber = '630',
elif Size=='9.5':
    sizenumber = '640',
elif Size=='10':
    sizenumber = '650',
elif Size=='10.5':
    sizenumber = '660',
elif Size=='11':
    sizenumber = '670',
elif Size=='11.5':
    sizenumber = '680',
elif Size=='12':
    sizenumber = '690',
elif Size=='12.5':
    sizenumber = '700',
elif Size=='13':
    sizenumber = '710',
elif Size=='13.5':
    sizenumber = '720',
elif Size=='14':
    sizenumber = '730',
elif Size=='14.5':
    sizenumber = '740',
elif Size=='15':
    sizenumber = '750',
elif Size=='15.5':
    sizenumber = '760',
elif Size=='16':
    sizenumber = '770',
```

and then where i am using 'sizenumber'

'pid': onlypid + '_' + sizenumber

the 'pid' on the site consists of the product id which i have set as onlypid then _ sizenumber, (productid_sizenumber)

the error i keep getting is 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects, any tips or solutions are greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong line. Actually, it produces not a string, but a tuple:

```
sizenumber = '670',
```

In real life you should read it as follows:

```
sizenumber = ('670',)
```

So actual type is a tuple. Just remove ',' in the end, it should work as you expect.

Comment: this is still a tuple which python cannot concatenate, i am looking for a way to put sizenumber into the data

Comment: @Nick Did you remove all commas everywhere? It can't be tuple. Or there is an error somewhere else.

Comment: yes there are no commas, and i am getting same error

Comment: actually there was, i removed it, i am sorry, thank you